# Why does casting based on Class.class work but not getClass?

Tags: java, class, generics, casting

I've got the following 3 tests. The first two work, the last one doesn't. My motivation for asking this question is that I'd like to be able to cast object `A` so that it has the same class as object `B`, when `A` is known to be a subtype of `B`.

```
  @Test
  public void testWorks() {
    Object bar = "foobar";
    String blah = (String) bar;
    System.out.println(blah); // Outputs foobar
  }

  @Test
  public void testAlsoWorks() {
    Object bar = "helloworld";
    String blah = String.class.cast(bar);
    System.out.println(blah);  // Outputs helloworld
  }

  @Test
  public void testfails() {
    Object bar = "foobar";
    String thetype = "hello";
    Class stringclass = thetype.getClass();
    String blah = stringclass.cast(bar); // Compiler error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String                                                                                                            
    System.out.println(blah);
  }
```

Can anyone explain why the last case fails when the first two succeed, and why this is the case? And what would be a better approach to achieve this?

Comment: I'd assume because .class is evaluated at compile time, but .getClass() is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: The compiler should have warned you about the use of the raw type `Class` instead of the parameterized type `Class<>`, which would be your hint that something is wrong with that declaration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to specify the type parameter of `Class`:

```
Class<String> stringclass = (Class<String>) thetype.getClass();
```

or

```
Class<? extends String> stringclass = thetype.getClass();
```

`java.lang.Class.cast(Object obj)` casts an object to the class or interface represented by this Class object.

Without specifying the type, you are not telling the compiler what class or interface is represented by the `Class` instance `stringclass`.

When you call `String.class`, the `Class` object is implicitly parametrized with the `String` type.

Answer (score 11):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) states

> The type of `C.class`, where `C` is the name of a class, interface, or
>   array type (§4.3), is `Class<C>`.

So the type of the expression

```
String.class
```

is `Class<String>`. `Class` is a generic class where the method [`cast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-) uses the generic type variable in its return type. So the result of

```
String.class.cast(bar);
```

is an expression of type `T`, where `T` has been bound to `String` in this invocation.

The return type of [`Object#getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) is `Class<? extends T>` where `T` is the erased type of the expression it's invoked on.

In this case, that is

```
Class<? extends String>
```

However, you are assigning it to a raw reference.

```
Class stringclass = thetype.getClass();
```

Since the variable `stringclass` is [raw, any uses of its methods that depend on the generic type variable are erased.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

So `Class#cast(Object)` now has a return type of `Object` which is not assignable to a `String` variable.

Had you done

```
Class<? extends String> stringclass = thetype.getClass();
```

you'd be fine.